# Opening a new panel by just clicking a portion of the panel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, mouselistener

I am using Net beans drag and drop GUI and in that i am displaying a chart in a jPanel and i want that when i click a portion of that chart then another panel opens up.I know we can  write an event , when we click a whole panel(anywhere in panel) but i just want that  when i click the small potion of that chart only then another panel opens up, how is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to the panel.  Detect the events, take action.  See [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.